# How to use Raspberry PI 2 without screen and keyboard?

Tags: ssh, hdmi, connection, laptop

I have a windows8 laptop (with SD card reader) and a raspberry 2. It works well if I connect it to a monitor and a keyboard at home. But how is it possible to use it, if I'm not home, and I can just use my laptop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH is a good way to access the command prompt over a network, via ethernet or wifi. VNC is a good way to access the desktop of your pi over a network. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/